# How to go from a wave to a particle description of photon dynamics in curved spacetime?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, photons, hamiltonian-formalism, qft-in-curved-spacetime

The general interaction of EM fields with gravity is given by,

$$ S = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$$

for EM [field tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime) $ F_{\mu \nu}$ and $g$ is the determinant of the [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity)). Through the variational principle, this equation governs the motion of an EM wave in a gravitational field. We can think of this as the 'macrophysical' description.

Now, in GR the motion of a particle (e.g. a photon) is governed by the equations which result from the Hamiltonian,

$$ H = \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu} p_{\mu} p_{\nu}$$

$$\dot{x^{\mu}} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_{\mu}} \, \, \, ; \, \, \, \dot{p}_{\mu} = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial x^{\mu}} \ , $$

which $=0$ for a photon, and $p_{\mu}$ is the photon 4-momentum. This is the 'microphysical' description.

In some limit, it seems appropriate that the macrophysical and microphysical (i.e. the wave/particle) descriptions are equivalent.

**Is it possible to go from equation 1 (re EM action), to equations 2/3 (Hamiltonian approach?)**

Comment: This is the subject of geometrical optics in curved spacetime, explained in all its gory details in books such as Misner, Thorne and Wheeler or Schneider, Ehlers and Falco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The movement of photons in GR is obtained from the Maxwell equations in the limit of geometric optics:
Consider as an ansatz for the vector potential $$A_\mu = (a_\mu + \epsilon b_\mu )e^{i\psi/\epsilon} $$ with a small parameter $\epsilon$ and a phase $\psi$. The wave vector is defined as $k_\mu=\partial_\mu \psi$.
The Maxwell equations for the gauge potential (in Lorenz gauge and for vacuum) read as: $$\nabla_\nu\nabla^\nu A_\mu -R^\mu _\nu A^\nu =0$$ If we insert the vector potential here and read off the leading order we find that $k_\nu k^\nu=0$. This of course implies $0=\nabla_\mu(k^\nu k_\nu)=2k^\nu\nabla_\mu k_\nu$. A short calculation shows: $\nabla_\mu k_\nu=\nabla_\nu k_\mu$. Therefore we have: $$k^\nu \nabla_\nu k^\mu=0$$This means that the wave vector follows a null geodesic, which is the same result one obtains from varying a suitable action.
You can find a complete derivation for example in: Norbert Straumann, General Relativity, section 2.8